# Find function for graph

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry

I would like to find a function for the following graph:
[image]

I have drawn the graph myself, so not all subtle bends are to be replicated. I have noted the important points the graph should have in the picture (and even those could be tweaked a little bit if it makes things easier).

How would you go about this? I tried setting up a polynomial of degree four and solving a linear equation system, but the system did not have any solutions. I'd be happy for a solution, preferably with an explanation and maybe even the possibility for me to move the points a little bit.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Does the limit as $x\to\infty$ need to be $0$? If so, a polynomial is not the way to go...

Comment: If you want a polynomial it should have degree $3$.

Comment: @5xum: Preferably. I could also set (1,0) for the function and set all input data points with x>1 to x=1. Why can't this be achieved by a polynomial?

Comment: @David: How do you know? Even with this information I would be unable to find the proper function...

Comment: @user1809923 If $p$ is a polynomial of degree at least $1$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} p(x)$ can only be $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @user1809923 For any $n$ points $(x_k,y_k)$ with all the $x$ coordinates different, there is a unique polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ which passes through those points.  If you take the procedure you followed for a quartic and start with a cubic instead, it should work.  (Though, as pointed out by 5xum, it may not be an appropriate answer to your problem.)

Comment: @5xum: ah yes, I see, thanks :)

Comment: @David: okay, thanks. I was able to compute a polynomial that resembles my function drawn above. I guess it would do, but if anyone is able to find a more exact function (i.e. behavior for x to infinity) I'd be happy to accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

this might work  $$\frac{p(x)}{e^{x^2(x-.2)(x-.6)(x-1)}}$$ where $p(x)$ is your polynomial

Comment: if i see it correctly this function has a clear minimal point between (1.0,0.0) and x to infinity.